# Table Joined To Itself Appears Inefficient

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, join

My ultimate goal is to compare two rows (only two will exist) and for a specific type and determine if its rows values are greater than the other rows type values. The result I came up with seems to be unwieldy which leaves me to wonder if it can be done in a faster or more elegant way.

---

I have created sql fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe6ee8/4) which demonstrates the issue.

Say we are shipping cargo and our **main** route of type 1 needs to be compared to the **other** route type 2. Each route has a Wave value and a Roll value which need to be compared independently. *Note that other route types (except main, it is always uses) can be compared to `Main` of type value 1, but only two at a time*.

```
CREATE TABLE Shipping
(
[RouteID]         [INT]  NOT NULL,
[WaveValue]       [INT] NOT NULL, 
[RollValue]       [INT] NOT NULL

);

INSERT Shipping(RouteID, WaveValue, RollValue)
VALUES (1, 20, 2),  -- This is the main route
       (2, 10, 30); -- The other secondary route, (only 2 items ever in this table)
```

With the values currently in the table we expect that the MainsWave will be greater than the other's wave and the reverse for the Roll.

Here is the working sql, *note that the true end result is only concerned with `IsMainWaveGreater` and `IsMainRollGreater` but all columns are shown for debug*:

```
   SELECT Max1.RouteID
        , Max1.WaveValue
        , Max1.RollValue
        , MaxOther.RouteID
        , MaxOther.WaveValue
        , MaxOther.RollValue
  , IIF(Max1.RouteID = 1,
        IIF(Max1.WaveValue > MaxOther.WaveValue, 1, 0),
        IIF(Max1.WaveValue > MaxOther.WaveValue, 0, 1)) AS IsMainWaveGreater
  , IIF(Max1.RouteID = 1,
        IIF(Max1.RollValue > MaxOther.RollValue, 1, 0),
        IIF(Max1.RollValue > MaxOther.RollValue, 0, 1)) AS IsMainRollGreater
   FROM
    Shipping AS Max1
   INNER JOIN Shipping AS MaxOther ON Max1.RouteID > MaxOther.RouteID;
```

Since the row that could be read first and joined to the next may not be the Main route (*remember always value 1 in `RouteID` for main*), the sql has to have an `IIF` which checks on what type Max1 is and then swap the check/results accordingly.

Can this be optimized or even rewritten?

This is just one operation in a CTE process so other operations can be entertained.

Comment: Roughly how many rows are typically in the `Shipping` table? Do you want to compare every row to all the other rows of the table? I.e. if there are 100 routes, do you want to compare every route to the other 99 routes? Also, when you say "main route of type 1" and "other route type 2", is there a `Type` column as well - how to we know which route is the "main" and which is the "other"?

Comment: @DanielHutmacher The `Shipping` table should only have 2 rows. In real life it is a target table created on a CTE business logic born out of other CTE's. Main is always 'RouteId' of value 1. I will update the post.

Comment: nested ctes are an optimization disaster, but i guess they make your code more legible. also, what indexes do you have on this table? and i cant see sqlfiddle, could you please post the repro on this site? thanks!

Comment: @swasheck full repro schema spec is above in the example. You should be able to change it into a temp table on your local box and run with the example above. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @OmegaMan sorry, i couldnt tell what was going on with sqlfiddle so i didnt know if it was the same. so anyway, you mentioned CTEs. are these CTEs the equivalent of this `Shipping` table? if so, could you post the ddl for the base tables and a rough estimate of the row counts? also, having the CTE definitions would be nice as well. a self-joind CTE has a strong possibility of being evaluated twice since there isnt any guarantee of intermediate materialization with them.

Comment: @swasheck Don't worry about the CTE, its ancillary and I am not concerned about performance at all. As to rows, there can only be 2 rows.

Comment: The query you provided returns only one row because of `Max1.RouteID > MaxOther.RouteID` condition. So if I got you right, you can simplify the IIFs to just one entry - the Max1 will always be the second route because the RouteID is 2 and 2 > 1.

Comment: @yahor state that as an answer. Sounds good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With two rows per table any method will be good.

Since you are OK with hard-coding the value `1` for the main `RouteID` I'd do it like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Main.WaveValue > Other.WaveValue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsMainWaveGreater
    ,CASE WHEN Main.RollValue > Other.RollValue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsMainRollGreater
FROM
    Shipping AS Main
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            Other.WaveValue
            ,Other.RollValue
        FROM Shipping AS Other
        WHERE Other.RouteID <> 1
    ) AS Other
WHERE Main.RouteID = 1
;
```

It assumes that there are only two rows in the table, if there are more "other" routes, then specify their specific `RouteID` in the `CROSS APPLY` instead of `<> 1` to get only one row that's needed.

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe6ee8/6/1).